# Postgresql Database Backup

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I am developing a C# application and could not find any details on backing up the database using C#. I would like to provide the users of the application ability to save a backup of the database and so on

I would really appreciate if someone could provide information on this issue. The specification of the system I am using is:

**OS: Windows XP Pro/Windows Vista
DB: PostgreSQL
.Net Connection for C#: Npgsql**

I have Followed the way of approach like this as

```
public static Boolean myfile(String content,String path)
{
    Boolean result = false;
    try
    {                
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = path;
        info.Arguments = content;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = info;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();                
        result = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.writeline(ex.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and too i have passed parameters as

```
content:pg_dump --inserts -h x.x.x.x -U xxxx -n public  -w  xxxx > D:\sql\mysample.sql


path:D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\
```

i am  getting exception response as

**Access is denied**

Update 1:

i too used code like this to get permission as

```
//var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
//var writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, dirName);
//permissionSet.AddPermission(writePermission);
```

it does not help me out.

Comment: I think "access is denied" is pretty clear: the user running this program is not allowed to write that file. (Unless your error message actually looks different than what you posted).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ya that ok where should i have set permission in order to work it

Comment: Through the Windows "Security" settings of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Access denied suggests a file permission issue.  Maybe your user doesn't have permission to run pg_dump, or there is an issue writing the file output.

The first thing to do is to try to run it and just discard the output and see if you get the same error.  If you do not, you need to set file permissions (right click the directory, security,set permissions).  If you do, you have an issue running pg_dump (try the same with the pg_dump file).